# Why calling useState function is working without declaring it?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am struggling to understand the syntax of calling the setCount function in the example below. The setCount function was never declared, so why is the calling of it working here?

```
 3:  function Example() {
 4:    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
 5:
 6:    return (
 9:        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
10:         Click me
11:        </button>
13:    );
14:  }
```

Comment: What?! The setCount function *was* declared, it's one of the values returned from useState on line 4. And your title asks about calling *useState*, which you presumably declared via an import from react.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-what-do-square-brackets-mean

Answer (score 2):

`useState()`  returns a pair of values: A state and a function that updates it.

```
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

so count is state, setCount is the function that updates it . `useState` already makes a function ready for you to update the state.You need not write it explicitly.

`setCount(modifiedValue)` will set the count to modified value

Example code :

UseState will not exactly do this but this is for understanding

```js
const useState=()=>{
 return [ "createdReactState",(value)=>{
//react's internal code for modification of state"
console.log("Im here for modifying the state ",value) 
}]
}

//destructing assignment
const [count, setCount] =useState()
setCount(2);
```

More here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is called Destructuring_assignmen.
useState hook is returning a tuple of value and a function to mutate that value, you declare the names of those returned elements while destructuring the return tuple of useState.
you can check out this explanation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Yes right. I don't understand why the return of "setCount" is automatically its arguments in the parentheses?
 Intuitively I would write this: 
() => setCount(counter) { (counter + 1) return counter };
 Is this: 
() => setCount(count + 1); 
a shortcut?

Comment: a naive implementation of useState would be something such as:

function useState(initialState) {
let state = initialState;
function setState(newState) {
state = newState;
}
return [state, setState];
}

this is why the mutation function works the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

The setCount function was declared in this line

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

That's the syntax of useState: The first element of the array is your state variable and the second element is the function to set value to your state variable.
Hope it's clear.

Comment: Yes right. 
I don't understand why the return of "setCount" is automatically its arguments in the parentheses?

Intuitively I would write this:

() => setCount(counter) {
    (counter + 1) 
   return counter
   };

Is this:
() => setCount(count + 1);

a shortcut?

Comment: @coasterrel the thing you would intuitively write makes no sense. Are you trying to declare *another* function named setCount? You should really learn basic JavaScript and ES6 syntax before trying to add on React.

Comment: @jonrsharpe while true, the comment might be less helpful than you intend it to be. If someone doesn't know what they doesn't know ... I tried to provide an explanation in my answer.

Comment: and I deleted my answer to the 2nd question, because @jonrsharpe is enforcing only 1 question at a time - if anyone wants an answer to the other question, please notify me.